# Writing basic method that uses multidimensional array in Java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have this little bit of code

```
_grid[4][4].setText(_square[4][4].getTopColor() + ": "
            + _square[4][4].getHeight());
```

Eventually in my program, the text will change because the value of get.Height will change. Is there a way to write a simple program that sets text based on the coordinates of the multidimensional array?

So if the method was called, updateText, I could just do _grid[4][4].updateText(); and it would be the same as the code above. Or if I did _grid[0][12].updateText(), it would do the same as this:

```
_grid[0][12].setText(_square[0][12].getTopColor() + ": "
            + _square[0][12].getHeight());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to refactor that line into a method in the same class.

```
private void updateText(int row, int col) {
    _grid[row][col].setText(_square[row][col].getTopColor() + ": "
                + _square[row][col].getHeight());
}
```

If you want to make it a method of the `grid` items, you'll have to give more details. Do the items in the grid know about their corresponding `_square`s?